# Nlog дважды генерирует свойства LogEventInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog

Всем привет!

Делаю логирование на NLog 4.9. в приложении ASP.NET Core. 
Имеется следующий таргет конфигурации:

```
    <target xsi:type="File" name="jsonFile" fileName="${basedir}\${shortdate}.json">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">
        <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}"/>
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
        <attribute name="eventProperties" encode="false" >
          <layout type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true"  maxRecursionLimit="20"/>
        </attribute>
      </layout>
    </target>
```

- Я убрал некоторые свойства, чтобы не занимали много места.

Вызываю логгер слеюдущим образом:

```
            var eventInfo = new LogEventInfo
            {
                Properties = { { "var", "value" } }
            };
            _logger.Info(eventInfo);
```

Соответственно time и level отрабатывают как и требуется. 
А вот eventIinfo записыватся не совсем так как нужно.

```
{
  "time": "2019-11-05 22:04:19.0990",
  "level": "INFO",
  "eventProperties": 
  {
     "var": "value"
  },
  "var": "value"
}
```

Это общий пример и на нем не очень хорошо видно в чем именно проблема.
А вот реальный пример:
[image: Пример записи Логгера]

Проблема в повторном переписывании всех полей, которые я передаю через LogEventInfo. У меня вопрос, почему NLog так записывает, это проблема в конфигурации логгера или это такая фича и нечего с этим не поделать.

Мне нужно, чтобы записи остались только "eventProperties"

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `<layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">` ===> `includeAllProperties="true"`?

Comment: includeAllProperties не влияет на это. Я уже пытался  его удалить и это особо не помогло

Comment: Я просто гадаю, но что если поставить `includeAllProperties="false"` ?

Comment: Поставил, это оставила продублированные записи, но в eventProperties вообще пусто стало

Comment: У вас в xml две строки с `includeAllProperties`, вы, видимо, меняете вторую, а я советовал менять первую.

Comment: пожалуйста, на здоровье